# Is Sauron invincible when he has the One Ring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, sauron

In the opening battle of *The Fellowship of the Ring* (I can't recall the name of it), Sauron is putting in work killing many men with the swing of his weapon.  Eventually Isildur comes out with a hay maker and cuts off his finger resulting in the loss of the ring, which results in Sauron losing his power.

My question is, if Isildur didn't do that, would Sauron have destroyed the entire army that was on the field that day at the first scene in *Fellowship of the Ring*?  I am under the assumption that he is basically invincible when he has control of the One ring, or does he have an Achilles heel like the Witch-king did?

So, Besides destroying the One Ring, how can Sauron be defeated?

Comment: FWIW Isidur cuts the ring off of Sauron's finger only after he was already defeated.

Comment: @Himarm I think it's important to note that while yes, Sauron and the Wizards are all Maiar, the Wizards were given specifically mortal forms by the Valar, and only one "lifetime" in which to do their work; once they died, that was all they had (Note that the Valar weren't able to bring Gandalf back. Only Eru could do that). Sauron had no such limitations

Comment: If he were completely invincible, why would he need his orc army? He could have faced the opponent's army alone.

Comment: Plus, if cutting off the ring were the key, I'd put a ring on all my fingers...and wear ringmail.

Comment: I thought it was obvious that his Achilles heel is his finger with the ring on it hahaha

Comment: @Huangism - yep, obviously his fingers weren't invincible.

Comment: Sauron + Ring were vinced once before.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sauron is a Maia, sort of the Middle-earth equivalent of an angel (or fallen angel, in this case)<sup>1</sup>. So the real question is "can an angel be killed?" The closest we have to a comparison are the balrogs.

Balrogs are usually considered to be Maiar, fallen angels corrupted by Sauron's old boss Morgoth long before the events of *Fellowship*. And balrogs can be killed, but it's not easy. I can think of three instances where the death of a balrog is explicitly stated:

1. In *The Silmarillion* Ecthelion, an Elf-lord of Gondolin, kills Gothmog, captain of the Balrogs
2. Also in *The Silmarillion*, Glorfindel of Gondolin kills another balrog
3. In *Fellowship*, Gandalf kills the balrog in Moria

These events have two things in common: all of the beings who killed a balrog had once been in Valinor, Middle-earth's heaven, and they all died in the attempt. So it seems as though killing a balrog is possible, but exceptionally difficult; it takes a special kind of person.

By the time of the Last Alliance, I think the only remaining elf who had dwelt in Valinor was Galadriel<sup>2</sup> (The Wizards hadn't yet been sent to Middle-earth at the time), and she wasn't going to be fighting in the battle.

So no individual at the battle was capable of killing a lesser Maia, much less Sauron, a very powerful Maia, short of some astonishingly good luck. So could he have been overwhelmed by the entire army?

Sauron only lost one other conflict in the Second Age<sup>3</sup>, mostly because of the great Númenórean host at the height of their power and influence:

> [I]n the very nick of time the great armament of Tar-Minastir came in; and Sauron's host was heavily defeated and driven back. The Númenórean admiral Ciryatur send part of his ships to make a landing further to the south.
>
> Sauron was driven away south-east after great slaughter at Sarn Ford (the crossing of the Baranduin); and though strengthened by his force at Tharbad he suddenly found a host of the Númenóreans again in his rear, for Ciryatur had put a strong force ashore at the mouth of the Gwathló (Greyflood), 'where there was a small Númenórean harbour'. In the Battle of the Gwathló Sauron was routed utterly and he himself only narrowly escaped. *[...]* [B]roken and humiliated he returned to Mordor, and vowed vengeance upon Númenor.
>
> <sup><sub>*Unfinished Tales* Part 2 Chapter IV "History of Galadriel and Celeborn"</sub></sup>

It also probably didn't hurt the Númenórean cause that the One Ring was still very new to Sauron, and he presumably had not quite mastered it.

However, centuries after this event the Númenóreans fell, and lost the blessing of the Valar. By the time of the Last Alliance, Elendil and Isildur are the closest things to true Númenóreans still alive, and it takes both of them to take them down, with nearly-fatal effort. In *Fellowship*, Elrond (One of the few participants in that battle alive at the time) recounts the story of Sauron's fall:

> Gil-galad died, and Elendil fell, and Narsil broke beneath him; but Sauron himself was overthrown, and Isildur cut the Ring from his hand with the hilt-shard of his father's sword.

There are lots of ways to interpret that account, and Elrond is clearly condensing the story for the sake of convenience, but three things are clear:

1. Elendil died battling Sauron
2. Sauron was not completely defeated by Elendil<sup>4</sup>
3. Isildur had to cut the ring from Sauron's finger to end the battle

It took two men of Númenor, both of whom were alive when Númenor sank, to subdue Sauron. Their descendants at the time of *Lord of the Rings* have much-diluted Númenórean blood - I'd say that Aragorn is the only living man who can come even close to matching Isildur or Elendil and, as much as Sauron fears Aragorn, it's doubtful that he alone could match his ancestor's combined feat.

However, it is possible for Sauron to lose his form (about as close to death as a full Maia can get). This happened at least once, during the Second Age. Sauron was on the island of Númenor, and convinced the Númenóreans  to invade Valinor. They failed, obviously, and Ilúvatar himself sunk Númenor in punishment. Sauron was stuck on the island at the time, and although he wasn't utterly destroyed he lost the ability to assume a pleasant-looking form.

The tl;dr of all this is that it's not inconceivable that Sauron could be forced out of his current form by a sufficiently large and powerful force. However, it's unlikely that any such force remained in Middle-earth by the time of the Last Alliance.

However, even if they succeeded Sauron would not be dead; it's important to note that even after the destruction of the Ring Sauron didn't die: in *Return of the King*, Gandalf says that:

> he will be maimed for ever, becoming a mere spirit of malice that gnaws itself in the shadows, but can never again grow or take shape

---

<sup>1</sup> If we're drawing parallels to Judeo-Christian cosmology, it would be better to think of Maiar as a lesser order of angels; strictly speaking the Valar, often considered the "gods" of Middle-earth, are more accurately classed as angels (With Eru Ilúvatar as The One True God), and Valar and Maiar are technically the same kind of creature, just with a different level of power.

<sup>2</sup> As [Mike Scott](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66287/sauron-in-the-opening-battle/66291?noredirect=1#comment146102_66291) reminds me in comments, there's some debate over whether there are two Glorfindels or just one. See my [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65600/what-did-arwen-mean-when-she-saved-frodo/65607#comment132742_65600) here for the background knowledge. So it's *possible* that there was another elf walking around with the ability to at least kill a lesser Maia. Whether or not he could defeat one or Sauron's strength is purely speculative, because we no longer have any canon support.

<sup>3</sup> Sauron did, of course, lose occasionally in the First Age, but very infrequently and always against some very powerful beings. The most famous time is probably in the story of Beren and Lúthien, when Sauron is pressured into yielding Tor-in-Gaurhoth to Lúthien. In this instance he's subdued by Huan, a wolf-hound who formerly belonged to the Vala Oromë, and had been granted special powers. Not an ordinary fight.

<sup>4</sup> You can argue over how much Sauron was weakened by his fight with Elendil, and the Jacksonverse argues that it wasn't very much - he had enough fight in him to curb-stomp Isildur for a while - but it's clear that Sauron was still alive and kicking when Elendil was killed. What's not clear is how much effort it took Isildur to cut off the ring; it could have been little, it could have been nearly fatal.

Comment: It is stated in the simarillion that Sauron hid the ring and surrendered to the numenorians when he had no chance of winning the war. When Numenor fell he lost his physical body and returned to Middle-earth as a spirit and claimed the ring again. So no, he did not fight in that battle personally. If he had taken the ring to Numenor it would have been lost to the sea alongside his body.

Comment: Actually, according to the text, Elendil and Gil-Galad overthrew Sauron, then Isildur dealt him his death-blow and cut the Ring off. So not only could the Last Alliance have defeated him, it *did*. The idea that cutting the Ring off defeated and killed Sauron is movie-only.

Comment: @Hoffmann You are coreect; I'll update my answer shortly

Comment: @Shamshiel Do you have a reference for that? All I can find is Elrond's speech in *Fellowship*, where he says "Gil-Galad died, and Elendil fell, and Narsil broke beneath him; but Sauron himself was overthrown, and Isildur cut the Ring from his hand with the hilt-shard of his father's sword"; I can't find any reference to the exact sequence

Comment: Galadriel was not the only elf in Middle Earth at the end of the Second Age who had lived in Valinor. And the other one was Glorfindel, who had already killed a balrog once, died in the process, and been reincarnated by the Valar. So he could presumably have done it again.

Comment: @MikeScott Whether or not Glorfindel in *Fellowship* is the same as Glorfindel in *The Silmarilion* is a difficult question to answer. Tolkein flip-flopped on the subject, and I don't believe it was ever decisively settled - IIRC, Tolkein died before he could make up his mind. Nevertheless, it's an interesting exception so I'll add a note

Comment: @JasonBaker - "...Isildur cut the Ring from his hand with the hilt-shard of his father's sword" indicates that Isildur used a shard of Narsil, which had been broken shortly before when Elendil (Isildur's father) fell, to cut off the finger of Sauron upon which he wore the Ring. Thus it appears that the sequence of events is: 1. Elendil and Gil-Galad battle Sauron; 2. Elendil and Gil-Galad are killed by Sauron; 3. Sauron is so weakened by the fight that he collapses and perhaps dies (the interpretation of "overthrown" is hazy, to me); 4. Isildur cuts off Sauron's finger, One Ring included.

Comment: @BobJarvis Yeah, I think I've been convinced that there's enough ambiguity to modify my answer. Editing now

Answer (score 16):

I am primarily answering the second question:

> I am under the assumption that he is basically invincible when he has control of the One ring, or does he have an Achilles heel like the Witch-king did?

While extremely powerful, Sauron is not invincible. Several times throughout the writings of Tolkien we see Ainur not only being injured but also killed.

- Saruman is killed by Wormtongue
- Gandalf is killed by Durin's Bane (and vice versa)
- Gothmog, Lord of Balrogs, is killed by Ecthelion
- An unnamed Balrog is killed by Glorfindel
- Sauron's physical form is, along with all of Númenor, destroyed by Eru Ilúvatar
- Morgoth is physically injured in combat seven times by Fingolfin

Thus it is apparent that the Ainur in Middle-earth are vulnerable to physical threats. Tolkien himself directly commented on this:

> It was because of this pre-occupation with the Children of God that the spirits so often took the form and likeness of the Children, especially after their appearance. It was thus that Sauron appeared in this shape. It is mythologically supposed that when this shape was 'real', that is a physical actuality in the physical world and not a vision transferred from mind to mind, it took some time to build up. ***It was then destructible like other physical organisms***. But that of course did not destroy the spirit, nor dismiss it from the world to which it was bound until the end.
>
> -Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien - #200

Therefor it is entirely plausible that Sauron could have been defeated, at least temporarily until he once again regenerated, during the War of the Last Alliance.

Comment: incidentally Sauron was also defeated by Beren and Luthien and Huan in the Silmarillion

Comment: When Wormtongue stabbed Saruman, Saruman did not initially die. A spirit is seen rising from his body looking to the West. A breeze from the West dissipates the spirit like smoke. Metaphorically, it seems that Saruman as a Maia, though out of his mortal body was still a living Maia that was ostensibly denied admittance back to Aman and cast into the Abyss. 

Well okay, I guess that pretty much means dead.

Answer (score 7):

To directly answer your question, short and sweet, Sauron is clearly not invincible even with the One Ring. During the Battle of Mount Doom (I believe that's what it was called), the combined efforts of Gil-galad, Elendil and Isildur defeated Sauron while he was wearing the One Ring.

As previous posts have explained, Sauron is a Maia, a sort of deity-like immortal spirit. As Gandalf had explained to Frodo, destroying the Ring wouldn't technically kill Sauron, rather it would reduce him to shadow in the dark gnawing at himself in the Abyss. So to you or I in Middle-earth terms, dead for all intents and purposes.

But besides destroying the Ring, what could defeat Sauron? Well Sauron is a Maia, and said to be of the highest order of Maia (Gandalf, the other wizards and Balrogs are Maiar as well). But again, he is only one Maia of many. Also, there are the Valar, to which the Maiar are subservient in class and power (you might say the Valar are the equivalent of Greek or Norse Gods). So what I'm getting at is that Ring or no Ring, the combined might of the Valar and Maiar could easily defeat Sauron.

So why go on a Ring quest when all of the Ainur (Valar and Maiar) can easily deal with Sauron? Well they actually had done just that against the First Dark Lord, Morgoth at the end of the First Age. This brought about damage and upheaval to Middle-earth of apocalyptic proportions. So to avoid this fiasco again and to defeat Sauron in Middle-earth, the Valar send the Istari, five Maiar in limited (old man) forms to Middle-earth that we later come to know to be the Wizards. I assume the idea behind the limited forms serves as both initially a disguise from Sauron and to limit collateral damage in any confrontation.

There might have been other ways for the Wizards to defeat Sauron, but centuries of work on their part (well mainly Gandalf and Saruman) show that finding and destroying the Ring to be the easiest "Achilles' Heel" approach.

Comment: I agree with most of your answer, but your assumption about the wizards is wrong, or at least incomplete. The Valar learned through the utterly disastrous War of the Jewels (which they indirectly caused) and the War of Wrath (which caused Beleriand to be sunk into the sea) that direct intervention in the affairs of Middle-Earth is a Bad Idea. The reason for limiting the Istari is so that they can only help through counsel

Answer (score -7):

Yes, very much Sauron was invincible when he has the one ring. He lost the ring because Isildur had a magic sword which could cut through anything, i forgot what it was called i know it was known as the flame of the west, forged by elves made of the shards of narsil.

I remember the sword was anduril yes the only object capable of defeating Sauron if the wielder knew what to do. Sauron lost to Isildur because he tried to grab isildur instead of killing him and Sauron didn't know what the sword was capable of, if he did he would have used his giant mace to defend himself.

If they had a rematch Sauron would have defeated him and made him a ring wraith like he does in the future. Well all said yes Sauron would have single handedly defeated Isildur and his army. also Sauron never wanted Isildur dead he wanted to make him his ring wraith.

Proof of this is when Sauron sends his orcs kill Isildur and get the ring back. But what happens instead is the ring is lost and they retrieve his body. after that they take him to Mordor to the tower of baradur then Sauron puts one of the rings of men on his finger then he comes back to life as a wraith.

But when he is asked where the ring is he responds.'' i lost it'' which Sauron gets pissed.

Comment: Per the comment on a previous one of your answers could you [edit] this to include proper capitalisation and also add in paragraphs to ease reading it. Also any supporting evidence, such as quotes, would go a long way to improving this.

Comment: did you dislike my answer because of this?

Comment: Without any quotes, your answer is basically worthless as it is impossible to determine if what you say is headcannon/interpretation or indeed a proper answer. Also, you contradict yourself by saying "he is invincible but could be defeated by a magic sword". So, he's not invincible but it takes a special weapon to defeat him.

Comment: There is no evidence in the books or movies for virtually any of your assertions.

Comment: there is plenty go back

Comment: shade is right about being not completly invicible but maia can hurt him when he has the ring i doubt they can kill him

Comment: please tell me your arent those people who say gandalf can beat sauron when sauron has the ring

Comment: Yesterday some fanboys argued with me that gandalf the white could defeat sauron when he has the ring which is not true!!!!!!

Comment: also what shade said i did contradict myself by saying that but he is invicible i mean if sauron had a 1v1 with isildur and isildur used narsil sauron would win because he could his is mace to defend himself and his speed agility and strength are tons better than isildurs and ontop of that the ring boost that so he dosesnt stand a chance also sauron could have had followers kill isildur and take the sword and throw it in mount doom and destroy it once and for all then he would be invicible

Comment: so if Sauron had followers kill isildur then throw narsil in mount doom then sauron would be quote on quote invincible

Comment: also narsil was the only weapon capable of killing sauron so like i said many times if thats destroyed then nothing can kill sauron

Comment: no one gonna answer back?

Comment: people always comment once and never come back LOL!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Madden If you don't reference to a person like I did, they don't get a notification that you've answered and will probably not check your answer again. As mentioned, you're pulling a lot of head cannon but don't "proof" it via quotes from a reliable source. That's basically what we avoid here. So, if your answer would be something like "Narsil can hurt him" - Quote - "Narsil has been destroyed or cannot be found anymore" - Quote - "Other weapons cannot destroy him" - Quote - "There is currently no known weapon that can hurt him" - Quote, it would be a great answer (IMHO).

Comment: that shit is boring im fine

Comment: this stuff is well known anyways i dont have to quote anything if people know it

Comment: @Madden No, this answer, which ought to have been deleted long ago for just how wrong it is, has nothing 'well known' in it.  You have no idea what invincible means, you think Anduril existed thousands of years before it did (Isildur used the shards of Narsil, not Anduril), you think the Orcs at the Gladden Fields had any idea about the Ring being there, you somehow seem to think Sauron made Isildur into a Ringwraith.  You basically did not get a single thing right other than (most of) the names.